# .NET Regular Expression allow 3 repeated characters

Tags: .net, regex, criteria

I'm trying to create a .NET regular expression with the following criteria below but no go. All I have is the regular expression below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

1. 8-15 characters (alpha or numeric and not case sensitive)
2. maximum of 3 repeated characters or numbers allowed
3. No special characters or symbols

This is what I've got:

```
^(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[A-Za-z].*)([0-9A-Za-z]\1{3}){8,15}$
```

Comment: Your regex looks like you want at least one digit and one alpha. Is that correct?

Comment: @bobblebubble yes, rock was able to provide! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work

```
^(?=.{8,15}$)(?!.*?(.)\1{3})[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG2yX3/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
(?=.{8,15}$) #Lookahead to check there are 8 to 15 digits
(?!.*?(.)\1{3}) #Lookahead to determine that there is no character repeating more than thrice
[A-Za-z0-9]+ #Match the characters
$ #End of string
```

For `unicode` support, you can use

```
^(?=.{8,15}$)(?!.*?(.)\1{3})[\p{L}\p{N}]+$
```

**NOTE** :- For matching one character and one digit, you can use

```
^(?=.{8,15}$)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*?(.)\1{3})[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG2yX3/4)**

Comment: how about merging that [first length check lookahead into the match](https://regex101.com/r/vN8gD1/1) or maybe have overseen something.

Comment: @bobblebubble but that will help in faster failure if the length is not matching

Comment: It also does not support Unicode. No idea if it matters though.

Comment: Good, but your length checking lookahead is redundant because you only have one character class in the consuming part of the pattern that can be quantified with a limiting quantifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using it because it will lead to faster failure in _some cases_..**[here](https://regex101.com/r/uG2yX3/2)** 

and **[here](https://regex101.com/r/uG2yX3/3)**

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks so much! Another question if you don't mind though but what if I need to have at least 1 numeric value and at least one alpha?

Comment: @rock321987 you are so awesome!! Thank you!!